# Android: Two Images in their Image View must touch each other

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I am having two Images in two different ImageView and the Layout in LinearLayout and vertical orientation.
Now I want to Touch Frist image border(bottom part to) to other image's Top part . but in android by default it gives some space between them.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

I want that , these Images touch each other. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 android:layout_marginTop="-12dip"
```

in your second imageView
and 12dip change to your own num, notice that it is negative num.

and second way, use RelativeLayout can satisfied you.

Comment: Another alternative is to get rid of padding instead of the margin. Padding set to 0px might be easier to read. :)

Answer (score 0):

Set android:padding to "0dp" and android:layout_marginTop/Bottom to "0dp" as well. Then there should be no reason they don't touch.

Also make sure your resources (png/jpg/etc) do not have extra transparency around the edges, as that will count towards the picture.